# Wordpress Subdirectory point to Root Directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

i am facing issue regarding WordPress Website. i want to point **sub directory** to **Root Directory**.

Means my current URL is

**www.abc.com/v1/**

which i need to redirect to

**www.abc.com/**

i try few ways but all not working. i am currently using **WordPress 4.5.3**

one of them is below URL.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Move whole WordPress to root path, update `www.abc.com` in database. Done

Comment: you can use .htacess

Comment: @siddhesh i am already using actually. but it is not working. i copy the Index.php and .htaccess file from Subdirectory and Copy to Root directory and change the path in index.php in root directory but still same problem

Comment: you doesn't need to copy  index.php and .htaccess keep them where they are just create new .htaccess file in  your public_html or www whatever it its and rewrite all request related to abc.com to abc.com/v1 for how to check .htaccess tutorial on google.